# Find largest non-contiguous subset of a binary array only containing ones

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I have a 2-d binary array, for example:

```
A = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
     [1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
     [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

I am looking for a well-scaling algorithm to find the *largest possible non-contiguous sub-array, only containing ones*.
**[Edit:]**
By **non-contiguous sub-array** I mean an arbitrary sub-set of columns and rows of the original array. This is equivalent to gradually removing rows or columns from the original array with the aim of removing the '0's.

The result should be two lists, a list of column indices and a list of row indices. The sub-array is defined as the intersection of all columns specified in the column index list and all rows specified by the row index list, i.e. all elements where the column index is in the column list and the row index is in the row list.

In this case the (zero-based indexed) result is

```
cols = [0, 2, 3, 4]
rows = [0, 2, 3, 4]
```

yielding a 4x4 sub-array, while for example:

```
cols = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
rows = [0, 2, 4]
```

is considered sub-optimal, as it only yields a 3x5 sub-matrix.

**[Edit:]**

By now I am using an algorithm, where I iteratively remove that column or row, which has the lowest percentage of '1's, until no '0's are left, while I have to recompute the percentage after each removal.

This actually gives some result, however, **I am not sure, if this is optimal in terms of maximum number of '1's.**

The following code implements this algorithm in Python using numpy:

```py
def find_subset(input_array, threshold):

    row_sel = list(range(input_array.shape[0]))
    col_sel = list(range(input_array.shape[1]))

    boolean_array = (input_array <= threshold)

    while not np.all(boolean_array):
        row_hitrate = np.average(boolean_array, axis=1)
        col_hitrate = np.average(boolean_array, axis=0)

        row_hitrate_amin = np.argmin(row_hitrate)
        row_hitrate_min = row_hitrate[row_hitrate_amin]

        col_hitrate_amin = np.argmin(col_hitrate)
        col_hitrate_min = col_hitrate[col_hitrate_amin]

        if col_hitrate_min < row_hitrate_min:
            # delete column
            boolean_array = np.delete(boolean_array, col_hitrate_amin, axis=1)
            del col_sel[col_hitrate_amin]

        else:
            # delete row
            boolean_array = np.delete(boolean_array, row_hitrate_amin, axis=0)
            del row_sel[row_hitrate_amin]

    return row_sel, col_sel
```

Comment: No example work, bad explanation... I believe no one will help you untile you improve your question

Comment: What is a "non-contiguous sub-array"? Define your terms.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have updated the questions in order to clarify my question.